# Ionic Angular - Desktop sidemenu minimized to the side instead of completely hidden

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, menu, ionic3, ionic4

By default in Ionic, the sidemenu will be expanded or hidden by sliding in/out from the side of the screen everytime we click on it.
However, specific for desktop version, I wanted it to be minimized (instead of completely hidden) to the side of the screen (so we can still see the icons on the left side of the screen) when toggling in.

Can this be achieved by modifying the css on either 
`ion-menu` or `ion-split-pane` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe not. you want something like this:

Opened:

[image]

Closed:

[image]

And I'm pretty sure it's not possible using the Ionic UI kit. you have to create your own component.